# Prove that the product of 2 positive natural numbers is also positive.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, peano-axioms

First time doing real analysis, using Tao's Analysis I, and I'm stuck in the second problem (2.3.2) If n and m are both positive, then nm is also positive. How do I prove such an obvious statement? I think I have to use the peano axioms and induction, using as base case n = 1, but I really don't know what would be my induction hypothesis (both n and m are positive?).

Comment: Your induction hypothesis could look like this. For a given, positive $n$ we have that $mn$ is positive for every positive $m$. Then $m(n+1) = \ldots$ is also positive.

Comment: So now I just prove m(n + 1 ) right? Thanks!